# How to reset paragraph numbering done with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have several paragraphs inside a single div container:

```
<div id="divNumbers">
    <p>One</p> <p>Two</p> <p>Three</p><p>Four</p> <p>Five</p>
</div>
```

Upon a button click,  I add numbers to each paragraph using jQuery:

```
$("#btnNumberPs").click(function () {
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        $("#divNumbers p").eq(i).prepend((i + 1) + ". ");
    }
});
```

This works fine. However, upon second click of the button I would like to reset this first, in order to avoid double numbering of the paragraphs. I tried to use the `reset()` method but it is not working. Can you please help me out or give me the idea what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Adding numbers to each inner paragraph is like making it into an ordered list, so I'll go with actually replacing the `<div>` element with a `<ol>` element upon button click, then replace back with `<div>` upon second click, etc. This requires more code, but is much more flexible and feels more correct than just adding numbers.

```js
$("#btnNumberPs").click(function () {
  var oContainer = $("#divNumbers");
  var items;
  if (oContainer.length == 0) {
    oContainer = $("#listNumbers");
    items = oContainer.find("li");
    var oDiv = $("<div></div>").attr("id", "divNumbers");
    items.each(function() {
      var contents = $(this).html();
      var item = $("<p></p>");
      item.html(contents);
      oDiv.append(item);
    });
    oContainer.replaceWith(oDiv);
  } else {
    items = oContainer.find("p");
    var oList = $("<ol></ol>").attr("id", "listNumbers");
    items.each(function() {
      var contents = $(this).html();
      var item = $("<li></li>");
      item.html(contents);
      oList.append(item);
    });
    oContainer.replaceWith(oList);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divNumbers">
    <p>One</p> <p>Two</p> <p>Three</p><p>Four</p> <p>Five</p>
</div> 
<button type="button" id="btnNumberPs">Toggle Numbers</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `substring` to reset your text.You may also use `disabled` attribute for button  to prevent adding multi-pal number like below.

```js
$("#btnNumberPs").click(function() {
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $("#divNumbers p").eq(i).prepend((i + 1) + ". ");
  }
  $(this).prop("disabled", true);
  $("#reset").prop("disabled", false);;
});
$("#reset").click(function() {
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $("#divNumbers p").eq(i).text($("#divNumbers p").eq(i).text().substring(2));
  }
  $('#btnNumberPs').prop("disabled", false);
  $("#reset").prop("disabled", true);;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divNumbers">
  <p>One</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <p>Three</p>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Five</p>
</div>

<button id='btnNumberPs' type="button">Num!</button>
<button id='reset' type="button">Reset!</button>
```

Comment: Although OP didn't ask for, this doesn't work with indices >9.